# Check all radios with the same xpath - robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have 3 radio buttons in a form which have to checked by robotframework. Below is part of the html code:

```
  <div>
    <div>
    <label for="doc-22-Confirm">
    Confirm
    <input id="doc-22-Confirm" class="radiocheckbox" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Confirm" name="data[doc-22]"/>
    </label>
    <label for="doc-22-Reject">
    Reject
    <input id="doc-22-Reject" class="radiocheckbox" type="radio" value="Reject" name="data[doc-22]"/>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="doc-23-Confirm">
    Confirm
    <input id="doc-23-Confirm" class="radiocheckbox" type="radio" checked="checked" value="Confirm" name="data[doc-22]"/>
    </label>
    <label for="doc-23-Reject">
    Reject
    <input id="doc-23-Reject" class="radiocheckbox" type="radio" value="Reject" name="data[doc-22]"/>
    </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Ids are dynamic. So I'm trying to check all radios with this code but it just select one of them:

```
click element  xpath=//input[contains(@id,'Confirm')]
```

I even tried this:

```
click element  xpath=//input[contains(@id,'Confirm')][1]
click element  xpath=//input[contains(@id,'Confirm')][2]
click element  xpath=//input[contains(@id,'Confirm')][3]
```

But still it doesn't work.

Comment: When you tried the set of three calls to `click element`, what happened? Did it click any? Did it click some? Did it throw errors?

Comment: It just click the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Click element  xpath=(//input[contains(@id,'Confirm')])[1]
```

I added the '( )' , it should solve the issue.